# How can I find the required parameters for a function imported from a DLL file using ctypes?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, ctypes, python.net

I'm trying to run some motor controllers using a library supplied by Maxon. The library is a DLL file that I'm reading in using ctypes and pythonNet. The library is working, I can drive the motors and most functions I've used so far have been fine. However, to read position data back from the controller I need to use a function called VcsGetObject. Every call I've made to the function has resulted in an error because I don't have the proper inputs or outputs:

> TypeError: No method matches given arguments for VcsGetObject

The VcsGetObject function accepts a data input by reference and returns position data through that variable. I've tried various methods of passing data to the function but haven't been successful yet. I've tried giving the function extra outputs, since I've read that PythonNet can do that automatically. I've tried passing in tuples or lists, or passing ctypes datatypes using ctypes.byref().

I'm honestly not sure where the problem is, and I want to know if there's some way to look at what the function expects in. I have documentation for the C++ function, but since I'm importing it from a DLL I can't really tell where the problem is. I apologize for the vagueness of this question, I honestly feel like there are so many places this could be going wrong but maybe there's something really obvious I just don't know about.

```
import time
import clr #pythonnet, manually installed with a downloaded wheel and pip
import ctypes #module to open dll files
import System
clr.AddReference('EposCmd.Net')
EposCmd64 = ctypes.CDLL('.\EposCmd64.dll')
from EposCmd.Net.VcsWrapper import Device

print("START")
print()

Device.Init()
nodeID = 1
baudrate = 1000000
timeout = 500
errorCode = 0
index = int('0x606C',16)
subindex = 0
dataLength = 4

# These functions all work as expected, so the library is being imported correctly
keyHandle, error = Device.VcsOpenDevice('EPOS4', 'MAXON SERIAL V2', 'USB', 'USB0', errorCode) #opens EPOS
print(errorCode)
Device.VcsSetProtocolStackSettings(keyHandle, baudrate, timeout, errorCode) #set baudrate
Device.VcsClearFault(keyHandle, nodeID, errorCode) #clear all faults

# # Trying to use lists or tuples doesn't work
#data = [0]
#readLength = [0]
#output = Device.VcsGetObject(keyHandle,nodeID,index,subindex,data,readLength,errorCode)

# # Using ctypes and .byref(), also doesn't work
#data = ctypes.c_byte()
#readLength = ctypes.c_byte()
#output = Device.VcsGetObject(keyHandle,nodeID,index,subindex,ctypes.byref(data),ctypes.byref(readLength),errorCode)

# # Trying to use PythonNet to turn by ref inputs into outputs
output, data, readLength = Device.VcsGetObject(keyHandle,nodeID,index,subindex,errorCode)
#print(data)
#print(readLength)
```

I've included links to the maxon documentation, GetObject is in section 4.1.4.
https://www.maxongroup.com/medias/sys_master/8823917281310.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your function calls looks incorrect. This is untested, but your open device call should look more like:

```
from ctypes import byref, c_byte, c_void_p
from ctypes.wintypes import WORD, DWORD

# Set type
errorCode = DWORD()

# Pass error by reference
handle = Device.VcsOpenDevice(
    'EPOS4',
    'MAXON SERIAL V2',
    'USB',
    'USB0',
    byref(errorCode))

# Read error code after function call
print(errorCode.value)
```

According to your linked doc `VCS_GetObject` looks like this:

```
nodeId = WORD(1)
objectIndex = WORD(0x606C)
objectSubIndex = c_byte(0)
NbOfBytesToRead = DWORD(
data = c_void_p()
# Vary this to read more or less data
NbOfBytesToRead = DWORD(4)
NbOfBytesRead = DWORD()
errorCode = DWORD()

return_value = Device.VcsGetObject(
    handle,
    nodeId,
    objectIndex,
    objectSubIndex,
    byref(data),
    NbOfBytesToRead,
    byref(NbOfBytesRead),
    byref(errorCode))

print(errorCode.value)
```

You should also set your restype and argtypes.